# Someone remotely encrypted my original source

Tags: php, encryption, obfuscation

I was having a remote session with someone 2 days back for a web application demonstration, and suddenly, I don't know what he did, but my screen froze for 10 minutes and then when it got back to work, all my main original source files were encrypted.

I don't have any back up and it took so much to code all that files but now all my work has gone to waste. When I opened those files, it says "Encrypted by PHPMasterCrypt and when I visited that website, it says its one-way encryption and cannot be reverted back.

```
<?$__C44s='This program is encrypted by PHP MasterCrypt - phpMC v2.6.0. This encryption system has been developed by Subhash Bose. Visit http://programming.subhashbose.com/phpmc for using phpMC';$__v=1879;if(!function_exists('c___65gf')){function c___65gf($__44re,$__4bd7,$__hdh7){return substr($__44re.$__44re,$__4bd7%strlen($__44re),$__hdh7);}}$m__hes7j='==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';$s___g6='__';$__v++;$m__c7df2=create_function(base64_decode('JG5fX2hmNzQsJGxfMzQzag=='),base64_decode('cmV0dXJuIGNyZWF0ZV9mdW5jdGlvbigkbl9faGY3NCwkbF8zNDNqKTs='));$m__065a3=$m__c7df2(base64_decode('JGhfXzY0M2g='),base64_decode('cmV0dXJuIGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoc3RycmV2KCRoX182NDNoKSk7'));$__C44s=base64_encode($__C44s);$m__a3e35=${'m'.$s___g6.substr(md5(c___65gf($__C44s,$__v,23)),8,5)}($m__065a3('=kjMmJ2XfRGJ'),$m__065a3('=sTKpkjMmJ2XfRGJoYXZyJHdzhSZ0FGbm5Wa6dGIuJXd0Vmc'));eval(strrev(${'m'.$s___g6.substr(md5(c___65gf($__C44s,($__v*3)*$__v,23)),8,5)}(${'m'.$s___g6.substr(md5(c___65gf($__C44s,$__v*$__v,23)),8,5)}(str_replace(md5($__C44s.'MC'),'',$m__hes7j)))));?>
```

Comment: Base64? Based on what? My advice, clear the server and reinstall it. Revert the source from a backup or from your source control system. There might be other backdoors into your server too, so just fixing the scripts might not be enough.

Comment: You may want to ask the other person what he did and why he did that?

Comment: @GolezTrol thats what am saying mate, I don't have the back up. Is it really a one-way encryption? Can't it be decrypted now?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 the other person is nowhere to be found now, everything he used to contact me turned out to be either non existent or turned off now

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but we're not here to deobfuscate your code for you.

Comment: But here's a hint: it *can* be reversed, it's just a royal pain in the butt. Replace `eval` with `echo`, take the result, repeat. Make sure to find any defined variables and keep them throughout.

Comment: @user2452 *"Is it really a one-way encryption?"* There's no such thing as one-way encryption - that would be closer to the definition of hashing. Anyway, is this even encrypted and not "just" obfuscated? (the difference being that obfuscation typically has the means to de-obfuscate the plain-text embedded in it somewhere).

Comment: @Niet: ...and watch out for the fact that there are a bunch of other ways than plain `eval()` to get PHP to evaluate a string as code. `create_function()` is the obvious one, but for example `preg_replace()` with the `e` modifier is particularly devious (and, fortunately, removed in PHP 7).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yeah, and `create_function` is indeed used in the above code. Caution is required, which is what makes it a royal pain.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have retrieved your code through sheer stubbornness.

```
<?php
require('mysql_func.php');
//ONLINE [REDACTED]
 define('GAPS_SERVER', 'localhost');                // eg, localhost
 define('GAPS_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
 define('GAPS_SERVER_PASSWORD', '[REDACTED]');
 define('GAPS_DATABASE', 'edaddy_irinfotech');

define('SITE_URL','http://localhost/edaddy');
define('SITE_ADMIN_URL','http://localhost/edaddy');
define('SITE_NAME','E-Daddy');
define('SITE_PAGE_REGISTRECTED','<div style="text-align:center;color:#FF0000" class="alert"><strong style="color:#FF0000">You do not have access to this page.</strong></div>');
//****** Table's Name of database ***********/// 
$SQLDB = array(
    'CRM_MENU'                         => 'crm_menu',
    'CRM_USERS'                        => 'crm_users',
    'CRM_MODULE'                       => 'crm_module', 
    'CRM_CUSTOMER'                     => 'crm_customer',   
    'CRM_DETAILS'                      => 'crm_detail', 
    'CRM_CASE'                         => 'crm_case',
    'CRM_SUBCRIPTION_TYPE'             => 'crm_subcription_type',
    'CRM_OPERATING_SYSTEM'             => 'crm_operating_system',
    'CRM_SYSTEM_CONFIG'                => 'crm_system_config',
    'CRM_RAM'                          => 'crm_ram',
    'CRM_HDD'                          => 'crm_hdd',
    'CRM_VERIFICATION_QUESTION'        => 'crm_verification_question',
    'CRM_REGISTERED_COMPUTER'          => 'crm_registered_computers',
    'CRM_CURRENCY'                     => 'crm_currency',
    'CRM_COUNTRIES'                    => 'crm_countries',
    'CRM_ZONES'                        => 'crm_zones',
    'CRM_CASE_STATUS'                  => 'crm_case_status',
    'CRM_TEAM_MASTER'                  => 'crm_team_master',
    'CRM_COMPONENTS'                   => 'crm_components',
    'CRM_CUSTOMER_CASE_TEMP'           => 'crm_customer_case_temp',
    'CRM_CUSTOMER_CASE'                => 'crm_customer_case',
    'CRM_TIMEZONE'                     => 'crm_timezone',   
    'CRM_CUSTOMER_NOTES'               => 'crm_customer_notes',
    'CRM_CASE_EDITED_DATE'             => 'crm_case_edited_date',
    'CRM_BREAK_MASTER'                 => 'crm_break_master',
    'CRM_USER_TIME_SLOT'               => 'crm_user_time_slot',
    'CRM_SETTINGS'                     => 'crm_settings',
    'CRM_CALL_TYPE'                    => 'crm_call_type',
    'CRM_CALL_MASTER'                  => 'crm_call_master',
    'CRM_CUSTOMER_CALLING_DATE'        => 'crm_customer_calling_date',
    'CRM_CUSTOMER_REACTION'            => 'crm_customer_reaction',
    'CRM_USER_RIGHT_MASTER'            => 'crm_user_right_master',
    'CRM_USER_RIGHT_CUSTOMER'          => 'crm_user_right_customer',
    'CRM_INTERNAL_EMAIL'               => 'crm_internal_email',
    'CRM_INTERNAL_EMAIL_USERS'         => 'crm_internal_email_users',
    'CRM_NOTICE_BOARD'                 => 'crm_notice_board',
    'CRM_NOTICE_BOARD_USER'            => 'crm_notice_board_user',
    'CRM_INTERNAL_EMAIL_REPLY'         => 'crm_internal_email_reply',
    'CRM_REFUND_REQUEST'               => 'crm_refund_request', 
    'CRM_CALL_DISPOSITION'             => 'crm_call_disposition',
    'CRM_KNOWLEDGE_MANAGEMENT'         => 'crm_knowledge_management',   
    'CRM_RESOURCE_MANAGEMENT'          => 'crm_resource_management',
    'CRM_NEWSLETTER_SEND'              => 'crm_newsletter_send',
    'CRM_USER_EMPLOYMENT'              => 'crm_user_employment',    
    'CRM_USER_ATTENDANCE'              => 'crm_user_attendance',
    'CRM_CAMPAIGN'                     => 'crm_campaign',
    'CRM_CAMPAIGN_EXPECTED_RESPONSE'   => 'crm_campaign_expected_response',
    'CRM_CAMPAIGN_STATUS'              => 'crm_campaign_status',
    'CRM_CAMPAIGN_TYPE'                => 'crm_campaign_type',
    'CRM_LEAD'                         => 'crm_lead',
    'CRM_LEAD_INDUSTRY'                => 'crm_lead_industry',
    'CRM_LEAD_RATING'                  => 'crm_lead_rating',
    'CRM_LEAD_SOURCE'                  => 'crm_lead_source',
    'CRM_LEAD_STATUS'                  => 'crm_lead_status',
    'CRM_QA_MASTER'                    => 'crm_qa_master',
    'CRM_QA_MASTER_TYPE'               => 'crm_qa_master_type',
    'CRM_QA_MASTER_USERS'              => 'crm_qa_master_users',            
    'CRM_CASE_FEEDBACK'                => 'crm_case_feedback',
    'CRM_INTERNET_OPTION'              => 'crm_internet_option',

    'CRM_QUALITY_REMARK'               => 'crm_quality_remark',
    'CRM_CHARGE_BACK'                  => 'crm_charge_back',
    'CRM_AVG_KEY'                      => 'crm_avg_key',
    'CRM_CLEAROMIZE'                   => 'crm_clearomize_key',
    'CRM_ANTISPYWARE'                  => 'crm_antispyware',
    'CRM_ANTIHIJACKING'                => 'crm_antihijacking',
    'CRM_BACKUP_TOOL'                  => 'crm_backup_tool',
    'CRM_OPEN_CASE'                    => 'crm_open_case',
    'CRM_CALL_SCHEDULE'                => 'crm_call_schedule',
    'CRM_REQUEST_CHARGEBACK_REFUND'    => 'crm_request_chargeback_refund',
    'CRM_USER_PENDING_ATTANDENCE'      => 'crm_user_pending_attandence',
    'CRM_ATTENDANCE_MASTER'            => 'crm_attendance_master',
    'CRM_UNRELATED_CALLS'              => 'crm_unrelated_calls',

);

 define('ERROR_MESSAGE','<div id="login_error"> %s</div>');
 define('SUBMIT_MESSAGE','<div class="message_div"> %s</div>'); 
 define('RECORD_DELETE','<div id="login_error"><strong>DELETE</strong>: %s</div>'); 
 define('RECORD_UPDATE','<div class="message_div"><strong>UPDATE</strong>: %s</div>');
 define('RECORD_INSERT','<div class="message_div"><strong>INSERT</strong>: %s</div>');
 define('RECORD_STATUS_CHANGE','<div class="message_div"><strong>STATUS</strong>: %s</div>');


$gaps_obj_1 = new gaps_sql(); 
$gaps_obj_1->gaps_connect();

$gaps_obj_2 = new gaps_sql(); 
$gaps_obj_2->gaps_connect();

$gaps_obj_3 = new gaps_sql(); 
$gaps_obj_3->gaps_connect();
error_reporting(0);
```

The process can be applied to any other files you have, <del>but considering the time and effort involved I wouldn't be able to do it for free =/</del>

On further review, I have succeeded in automating the process. I have created a tool that reverses this supposedly irreversible process.

You can find the tool here: <del>http://thedarkworld.net/phpmc260.php</del> The server has since been taken down, but I've re-created it in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjykgvn4/).

Comment: If you can automate this, you could make some money off other people who willingly let hackers into their system. ^^

Comment: @GolezTrol Automating it should be possible, but it could be risky. It would also risk getting into an arms race as phpMC could just change how it works, which I'd have to research and defeat...

Comment: can't you at least say what you did? it would be very interesting

Comment: @gbalduzzi I'll see what I can do. I've started a JS-based decryptor for this which is looking promising...

Comment: @gbalduzzi Success!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice one :) Your site doesn't seem to work properly in Firefox (some CSS from your poke-site keeps loading indefinitely and the javascript complains about an `invalid regular expression flag ?`). It could be my NoScript plugin acting up though. Anyway, it works perfectly in Chromium. I wonder why some people are down-voting...

Answer (score -2):

> and suddenly, I don't know what he did, but my screen froze for 10 minutes

Blind bet is that your app allows file uploads and this feature is very much broken in your code as you allow uploaded files to be reached directly if one knows the right url. I suggest to inspect upload folder however the uploaded PHP script that did the mess could self-remove too.

> it says its one-way encryption and cannot be reverted back.

There's no one way encryption as it would be no point of such.

> I don't have any back up and it took so much to code

"so much to code" and no backup, no VCS. Well...

Comment: This would have been a fine comment.

Comment: This is not the comment. This is the answer. FYI: this exceeds character limit of the comment and also you are unable to format the comment the way I formatted my answer. If I'd like to make comment I'd do that.

Comment: I know the limit of comments, but that doesn't make it right to post it as an answer.

Comment: You miss "in my opinion" in your comment. And that's the whole point.